# Java datagramsocket receives incomplete message

Tags: java, udp

I'm developing a small program that transfer string commands through network using udp.Most strings I send is received correctly,though one specific string is not completly received.I don't know if it's the sending side or the receiving side which have the problem.
Example of correctly received string: "connect 123.123.1.1"
The string which is not correctly received: "a/name/123.123.1.1" what I get when this is received: "a/name/123."
code for sending:

```
public  void sendToAll(String massage) {
    //send massage to all clients

    byte[] sendData = new byte[1500];
    //clients is a linked list
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
        String ip = clients.get(i).ip;
        sendData = massage.getBytes();
        try {
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 11222);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The code for receiving:

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1500];
while (true) {
      DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
      serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
      String massage = new String(receivePacket.getData());

      //operations for other commands

      if (massage.startsWith("a/")) {

            String[] info = massage.split("/");
            //operations for this command
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not currently know the cause of your problem, I found some things to look for in your code, and maybe one of them is somehow related to the cause of all this.
First, in the send method, you allocate a sendData buffer of size 1500 before encoding string commands into bytes. It is not needed, as the method getBytes() returns a new byte array. However, that really should not cause any problems.

What worries me more is the receive method, and that line:

```
String massage = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

As per java api documentation, the method getData() of packet will return a buffer passed to it. That buffer is 1500 bytes long, and trying to use a String constructor in that way results in taking the whole 1500 bytes. It probably should be:

```
String massage = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
```

Comment: cool. although it still makes me wonder why it worked like that before. it should be an overly long string, not a shortened one, I believe.